# Checking the database for new rows at regular intervals of time

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, web-services, asynchronous

I'm creating a web application in which I need to Check the Database in regular Intervals for any new rows Updated in the table. If any Rows have been updated and return the Rows to the user.

When I refresh the Page I update the rows in my Website. But I need to Know If any new Rows have been added to the Table without refreshing the Page

How can I achieve this ??
Can you suggest me a Method (Probably which doesn't slow down the web site).

Can I achieve this using web services??

Comment: If only your application uses this database, then you know when it is updated. Otherwise, you should rather have your application being notified by the DB of any changes rather querying for it.

Comment: When I refresh the Page I update the rows in my Website. But I need to Know If any new Rows have been added to the Table without refreshing the Page

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is using javascript to hit a page on your website with `setInterval` posting back to a page to ask about any changes, web sockets can do this real time but require modern browsers.

Here is a similar question that's been answered well, though it's for Asp.net MVC:

[Creating an AJAX alert for a user when there's a server-side change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629438/creating-an-ajax-alert-for-a-user-when-theres-a-server-side-change)

If I'm being forced to use vanilla ASP.Net I do usually put those kind of requests into a webservice.